# How can I stop an inline style from being modified by an outside script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On a page some script is running and is accidently controlling the height of an inline style.

Not sure what script is modifying the height property.

```
<div class="vgca-iframe-wrapper wpfa-initialized" style="height: 6424px;">
```

The height keeps going up and pushing all elements past the footer.
Trying to lock this class from being edited.

So far tried controlling the element in the css stylesheet to keep it locked at 3000px..

```
div.vgca-iframe-wrapper.wpfa-initialized {
    height: 3000px !important;
   
}
```

to no avail.. any help appreciated.  Open to ideas how to prevent this css style element from being changed.

Comment: Find and get rid of `some script` :D if it's modifying the inline style, I believe you could possibly discover the culprit by using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - if not discover, then undo its nefarious actions

Comment: You could try to specify the style as specifc as possible, maybe that would prevent it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @MatthiasThalmann , thought was doing so with the css provided.. have an example ?

Comment: You can also define the `max-height` property and set that to 3000px. I believe max-height will take precedence when height also exists. Test in different browsers, of course.

Comment: It is strange that your !important has not worked (though I don't know what the 'not-allowed' would do - I assume you've tried without that) as, if the script is just resetting the inline style attribute, your !important will work. This means it's doing more that that - perhaps rewriting the whole of that element or something? In which case @JaromandaX suggestion of a MutationObserver may be the only way to go. You'll have to look at every change in the page one by one.

Comment: @PeterKrebs tried that, but it still keeps changing., ty for your reply

Comment: @AHaworth removed that property, you're right doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PeterKrebs answer should work. Could you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see *exactly* what CSS is being applied to that element?

Comment: @AHaworth  `every change in the page` no - every change to that one element since something is changing the inline style (attribute)

Comment: @JaromandaXmy fear is that the HTML is actually being rewritten rather than that element staying in place and just the style being altered (if just the style was being altered then I think PeterKrebs solution should work).

Comment: To find the culprit, you can use a DOM breakpoint on attribute change in your browser devtools. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#dom

Comment: Did it work in the past and now it doesn't?  Is the code in a repository where you can review the history?  Is there any debugging information from dev tools, even just a basic element inspection?

Answer (score 1):

### Using `max-height`

The CSS property max-height will give the height an upper limit, even if `height` is higher. See snippet below:

```css
div {
  background-color: #a0a;
}

div.vgca-iframe-wrapper.wpfa-initialized {
    height: 20px !important;
    max-height: 20px;
    height: not-allowed !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="vgca-iframe-wrapper wpfa-initialized" style="height: 80px;">
```

Used 20px for your height and 80px for the height in the style attribute. As you can see the div stays and 20px height.

We don't even have to make max-height !important.

Comment: tried yours and tried this, still the problem is manifesting itself with the height property still being modified on the page. 

`code`
div.vgca-iframe-wrapper.wpfa-initialized {
    height: 20px !important;
    max-height: 20px !important;
    
}
`code`

Comment: Oh okay so the script is manipulating that dynamically. You will have to find the causing script with the MutationObserver people wrote about.

Comment: was hoping some css webkit or a javascript to stop inline edits to the div might work

Comment: Yes you can write a javascript to stop that but you have to find the javascript that modifies the height first. When you know the function you can make it empty: `Example.AdjustHeight = function() {};`. This will deactivate that function since it will execute nothing. You have to know the name of the function first of course and have to access it through `window` hopefully.

Comment: what is `css webkit`? CSS is not limited to the webkit family of so called *browsers*

Comment: @JaromandaX figured it out, it was an iframe lower down in the div that was causing the issue, changed the css to control the iframe with a max-height property and it stopped enlarging the div.  thanks anyways!